# how many subsets with 4-elements?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, combinations

I ran into a non-trivial question on one Statistics Book,

how many subsets with 4-elements from set {$1,2,...,10$} can be taken such that hasn't two consecutive number in that subsets.

> how we should be able to solve this?

Comment: Hello!  I think you misunderstood the point of this site.  It exists to help *you* find your own solutions to problems, not to provide answers to arbitrary questions.  Perhaps if you tell us exactly why you're interested in the question, what you've tried and where you're stuck, we'll be better placed to give you help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider a binary vector of size $10$, with exactly $4$ ones, such that if the $i$th bit is $1$ we take $i$ to our subset.

Now since we want that there wont be any $2$ consecutive ones, we'll start with $4$ ones and put between them one $0$, now we have $3$ more zeroes (since we spent $3$ for the gaps between our ones), and we can put them in those 3 gaps and as well before the first one and after the last one, to do that we have $$CC_5^3={{3+5-1}\choose {3}}$$

Comment: I want to approve, but I couldent get how 3,5,-1 comes from ?

Comment: It's the standard formula for the number of options to divide 3 identical balls to 5 different cells with repetitions and when order between the balls doesn't matter.

Comment: is it possible to add a bit more detail in you answer to approve?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination check out "Number of combination with repetition"

Comment: I confusing when read Wikipedia, please add a bit detail to approve.

Comment: you say, put fours 1. and between them put 3 zeros. then put 1 zero before the first one and 1 zero after the last one? is It right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate way to think of this:

Put 6 dots in a line, representing the 6 numbers not chosen.

Then put a line in 4 out of the 7 gaps, representing the 4 numbers which are chosen;

there are $\dbinom{7}{4}$ ways to do this.